# Dart Web-GL context is null

Tags: dart, webgl

I started my journey of Dart today, however I don't seem to be able to get WebGL context. Here is all the code I have.

```dart
CanvasElement canvas = querySelector("#area");

WebGL.RenderingContext gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
if (gl == null) {
  gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
}

if (gl == null) {
  querySelector("#console").text = "WebGL is not supported!";
} else {
  querySelector("#console").text = "WebGL is supported!";
}
```

And for html:

```dart
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Dart WebGL Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dart WebGL</h1>
    <p id="console">Trying to make a game work in Dart WebGL</p>

    <div id="container">
      <canvas id="area" height="400px"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Context is always equal to null. Any ideas why this happens? (I tried running this on Chromium and on Chrome)

Comment: But the browsers show this demo correctly https://www.dartlang.org/samples/solar3d/ ?

Comment: Yes 3D solar system demo is showing just fine. I'm getting some errors in Chromium that some API keys are missing. However I read about the error and someone said that it has no effect on developing with dart. Do you think it might be related?

Comment: I don't have any problems with your code. Which Version of Dart are you using?

Comment: The api keys are unrelated to the WebGl problem. Could be a device problem. Maybe restarting Dartium / your computer resolves the problem.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version from the Dart website today. I'm thinking something along the lines of missing some "app configuration" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. Such a mistake. The code I posted doesn't match the code I'm running, because I didn't think it mattered.

```dart
CanvasElement canvas = querySelector("#area");
var context = canvas.context2D; // this line here

WebGL.RenderingContext gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
if (gl == null) {
  gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
}

if (gl == null) {
  querySelector("#console").text = "WebGL is not supported!";
} else {
  querySelector("#console").text = "WebGL is supported!";
}
```

Didn't realize accessing a member would do something bad :D Sorry.

Comment: So the essence is, that you can't get a `context2D` **and** `webgl` from the same canvas?

Comment: I think so. But I wonder how does just accessing a variable do that. (Unless I have no idea what Dart is capable of)

Comment: `canvas.context2D` is probably a getter which looks like a field but actually contains code like a function and can have side effects. Usually it is bad practice to implement getters in a way that they have side effects (in this case a function should be used instead) but this code is probably generated form IDL (a description language) which might explain the 'mistake'.